# Calculate the length of an edge consisting of many pixel data

Tags: python, image-processing

I have made a workflow code to detect the edges of a flame in an image. I could get the edge line. It consists of many pixel points stored in an array (data in my code). Now based on the data, I would like to calculate the length of the edge. The idea is to calculate the distance between every point in data and sum them all to get the length. I really stuck in making that. Please help me, many thanks.

Here is a processed image:

[image]

Here is the original image that converted to the processed image, I put in the code is to compare the result:

[image]

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = '1897_1.jpg' #processed image
    pic = cv2.imread(path)
    original = cv2.imread('1897_2.jpg') #original image
    img2 = cv2.flip(original, 1)
    b,g,r = cv2.split(pic)
    img4 = cv2.flip(b, 1)
    h,w = img4.shape
    data = []
    th_val = 20
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            val = img4[i, j]
            if (val >= th_val):
                data.append(j)
                break

    b1 = range(len(data))
    b2 = len(data)
    result = [b2]
    print (b2)

    plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8))
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.imshow(img4)
    plt.plot(data, b1)
    plt.axis('off');
    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.plot(data, b1)
    plt.imshow(img2)
    plt.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a very simple solution, it is far from optimal, but it works for this example, and it is a good starting point. Unfortunately, this solution is not optimal for the blue chanell, where the curve is not smooth, but it works for green and red chanells.

`data` contains width coordinates of the first red pixel overcoming threshold. So, all first pixels are separated by 1 pixel step on vertical axes and `data[i+1] - data[i]` on horizontal axes. These two values can be considered as two cathetus of the squeare triangle, and the hypothenuse is the distance we want to calculate. So, here is the solution:

```
length = 0

for i in range(0,len(data)-1):
    cathetus = data[i+1]-data[i]
    hypothenuse = (cathetus**2 + 1**2)**1/2
    length += hypothenuse

print(length)
```

**Update**
I have came up with two solutions: a hardcoded one and one released in the form of the function. Let us start with the first one: `mean` is a rather good approximator for the signal + noise. In the situation, when you do not have very strong noise or missing data, you may use this approach. In the example below we select points with `x in [1,2,3]` then we calculate mean y for these points and assign mean to coordinate `x=2`. Next we select points `x in [2,3,4]` and so on. As a result, we obtain `mean_data` list with `y` coordinates and `mean_x` with `x` coordinates. We can calculate length with the approach described above. You may also increase the power of smoothing by averaging over 4 and more points from data.

```
mean_data = []
mean_x = range(1,len(data)-1)
for i in range(0,len(data)-2):
    mean_d = (data[i] + data[i+1] + data[i+2])/3
    mean_data.append(mean_d)
```

Another approach is to use smoothing tools from `scipy` package. One of them is described below. When calculating the length you will have to adjust to new x axes `xnew`.

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import numpy as np
#transform to np.arrays initial data
b1_ = np.array(b1)
data_ = np.array(data)
# create new x with more data points
xnew = np.linspace(b1_.min(),b1_.max(),50) #50 is a number of points in between 
smoothed_data = spline(b1_,data_,xnew)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution from a simple cool idea that made me like a dump. I overthought about it. The code works for my "data". I check again my images and see that the original image (mix red-orange one) is first used to convert to the edge image (processed image) and it is a grayscale image, I guess. So the fact that, if I change the to the red or green channel, the code still works well.

Comment: However, as you said, the code is better for the smooth curve,  I am working on making a local fitting line that consists of 2 to 3 pixel points after checking the discrete of the "data". If you have any idea about fitting method, I would love to hear. Thank you!